# Cloudflare Access Denied when running scrappy spider

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have created a scrapy spider but site's cloudflare protection blocks requests from scrapy while on browser site is working perfectly.

I Tried using user agent. Tried changing IP address.
I used cfscrape but that is also not working.
Nothing is working.

Comment: Are you using scrapy with python? how is your config file? are you limiting the requests / second? show your scripts and people will help you

Comment: You will have to use various proxy ips, there is no other way to get around CF using simple scrapy, or use a real browser like Splash, Selenium etc, because CF uses JS to solve a riddle when a page is loaded

Comment: It is even not working on urllib requests and cfscrape

Comment: If is there any solution to let it work with urllib or requests then that would be okay

Comment: could you provide the actual link?

Comment: https://www.vitals.com